# Redirecting all 404 errors to void or null via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do use mod_rewrite in my htacess and I am not sure this has anything to do with my problem. Here they are anyways:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(entry\.php|css|fonts|img|js|lib|plugins|resources|test|humans\.txt|404\.html|browserconfig\.xml|manifest\.json|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entry.php/$1 [L]
```

Basically everytime the browser does not find a ressource (usually an image) it messes up my rewrite url. I first discovered while using firefox because it always requests a "favicon.ico" no matter you do and I don't use such file.

Right now I am using this in my .htaccess to circumvent the problem:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RedirectMatch 403 favicon.ico
RedirectMatch 403 .gif
</ifmodule>
```

The .gif entry is because it also tries to find some .gif that I don't use.

So instead of listing every type of files here, is there a way to simply tell it that whenever it can't find a ressource to "403" it?

Thanks,

Erick P.

Comment: If the requested ressource doesn't exist, the webserver returns 404. If your webserver rewrites then to something else, then you should check your rewriting rules.

Comment: rewrite rules seem pretty simple..unless I'm missing the point:

RewriteCond $1 !^(entry\.php|css|fonts|img|js|lib|plugins|resources|test|humans\.txt|404\.html|browserconfig\.xml|manifest\.json|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entry.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

This directive is equivalent to Redirect, but makes use of regular expressions, instead of simple prefix matching. The supplied regular expression is matched against the URL-path, and if it matches, the server will substitute any parenthesized matches into the given string and use it as a filename. For example, to redirect all GIF files to like-named JPEG files on another server, one might use:

```
RedirectMatch (.*)\.gif$ http://www.anotherserver.com$1.jpg
```